# Quotient Rings of Polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, quotient-spaces, group-rings

Let $R = \mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Then $R/Rx$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]$.

*My Proof*

$R  = ax+by+c , a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$
and
$Rx = (ax+by+c)x , a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$

So, $$R/(R\cdot x) = (ax+by+c) + (a'x+b'y+c')x, a,b,c a',b',c' \in \mathbb{C}$$
$$ = by+c + (a'x+b'y+(c'+a))x, a,b,c a',b',c' \in \mathbb{C}$$
So the set of cosets of $R/(R\cdot x)$ is clearly isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]$.

> This argument feels incredible handwavy. Is there a more rigorous way to prove this?

(I know in some cases defining an appropriate ring homomorphism and finding the kernel gives us the isomorphism by the first isomorphism theorem, but I couldn't find a homomorphism that worked.)

Comment: I'd say $R=\mathbb C[x,y]=c+ax+by+dx^2+exy+fy^2+gx^3+hx^2y+ixy^2+jy^3+...$

Comment: When you typed $r$, did you mean $R$?

Comment: But still $R \cdot x$ has no terms with just $y$ and no constant terms correct? So when we mod out $R \cdot x$, we have two cosets: identity coset,  and one with all multiples of y @J.W.Tanner

Comment: correct; $Rx=cx+ax^2+byx+dx^3+..$

Comment: Thanks! Is there an approach that doesn't use the coset descriptions? or is this the most straightforward approach?

Comment: @Jess the standard way to prove that $R/I\cong R'$, where $R,R'$ are rings and $I\subset R$ is an ideal is to use the first isomorphism theorem. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Can you prove that
\begin{align*}
\Phi:\mathbf{C}[X,Y] &\longrightarrow \mathbf{C}[Y] \\
f(X,Y) &\longmapsto f(0,Y)
\end{align*}
is a surjective ring homomorphism? Its kernel is exactly $(X)\subset \mathbf{C}[X,Y]$ (why?).  Now you are ready to use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: But don't I need the kernel to be ($X \cdot \mathbb{C}[X,Y]$)?

Comment: This is just notation. We can denote the ideal by $(X)$ and $(X)\cdot \mathbf{C}[X,Y]$. Both mean the same thing: all polynomials in $X,Y$ with coefficients in $\mathbf{C}$ that are divisible by $X$.